# SQL Server JOIN performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, join

I have a performance issue with SQL Server joins where there are multi column comparison.

```
SELECT T1.* FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.LASTNAME = T2.LASTNAME AND
T1.FIRSTNAME = T2.FIRSTNAME AND
T1.MIDDLENAME = T2.MIDDLENAME AND
DAY(T1.DoB) = T2.DOBDay AND
MONTH(T1.DoB) = T2.DOBMonth
```

Each of those tables are above 20,000 records and it is really causing a performance issue.
I ran it and it was taking longer than 6minutes so I cancelled it!

Is there a way to increase the performance of that statement?

Comment: What indices do you have on both tables? What does execution plan say?

Comment: Check for indices on all the fields in where clause of both tables!

Comment: In the worst case, with no indices on either table, Each of 20,000 rows in T1 would need to compare to 20,000 rows in T2, resulting in a working set of 400MM rows. To establish that this problem is behind the screen rather than in front of it, provide some description of the available indices.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Ok, looks like I got confused with other tables. The indices weren't set up for both tables. silly me

Comment: Thanks marc_s. Didn't realise it was a depreciated style. For simple joins like that (2 datasets) I tend to use that JOIN styling but for more than 2 JOINs, I use the new method! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the below non cluster index on both your tables before..

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_First_Middle_T2  ON T2 (FIRSTNAME,MIDDLENAME);
```

Now the run the below query

```
SELECT T1.*,DAY(T1.DOB) as DOBDay, MONTH(T1.DOB) as DOBMonth INTO #T1
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_First_Middle_T1  ON #T1 (FIRSTNAME,MIDDLENAME); 

SELECT T1.*
FROM #T1 T1
JOIN T2
ON T1.LASTNAME     = T2.LASTNAME
and T1.FIRSTNAME   = T2.FIRSTNAME
and T1.MIDDLENAME  = T2.MIDDLENAME
and T1.DOBDay      = T2.DOBDay
and T1.DOBMonth    = T2.DOBMonth
```

The above query gives you two additional columns with the month and date, instead of T1.* replace it with the column names.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need data from T1 table you can use a left join or exists clause.

```
  select T1.* 
  from T1
  where
      exists (
                  select 1
                  from T2
                  where
                     T1.LASTNAME = T2.LASTNAME
                     and T1.FIRSTNAME = T2.FIRSTNAME
                     and T1.MIDDLENAME = T2.MIDDLENAME
                     and DAY(T1.DoB) = T2.DOBDay
                     and MONTH(T1.DoB) = T2.DOBMonth
             )
```

Comment: Hello I just tried this out and the performance seemed to have gone worse. Doubling the execution time time